# kubectl get pod <pod> -n <namespace> -o yaml in kubernetes client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

Now i have Pods as Kubernetes structs wiht the help of the command

```
pods , err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("namespace_String").List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
```

now i do i get it as individual yaml files
which command should i use

```
for i , pod := range pods.Items{
    if i==0{
        t := reflect.TypeOF(&pod)
        for j := 0; j<t.NumMethod(); j++{
            m := t.Method(j)
            fmt.Println(m.Name)
}
}
}
```

this function will print the list of functions in the pod item which should i use

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `yaml` is just a representation of the Pod object in the kubernetes internal storage in etcd. With your `client-go` what you have got is the `Pod` instance, of the type `v1.Pod`. So you should be able to work with this object itself and get whatever you want, for example `p.Labels()` etc. But if for some reason, you are insisting on getting a yaml, you can do that via:

```
import (
  "sigs.k8s.io/yaml"
)

b, err := yaml.Marshal(pod)
if err != nil {
  // handle err
}
log.Printf("Yaml of the pod is: %q", string(b))
```

Note that `yaml` library coming here is not coming from `client-go` library. The documentation for the `yaml` library can be found in: https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/yaml#Marshal

Instead of `yaml` if you want to use `json`, you can simply use the `Marshal` function https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/apis/example/v1#Pod.Marshal  provided by the `v1.Pod` struct itself, like any other Go object.

Answer (score 0):

To get individual pod using client-go:

```golang
pod, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("pod_namespace").Get(context.TODO(),"pod_name", metav1.GetOptions{})
if err!=nil {
  log.Fatalln(err)
}
// do something with pod
```

Comment: How to get yaml of that pod??